# Shift invariance of system example

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems

I'm preparing for upcoming exam.
I'm having difficulties with deciding if system is shift invariant.
System is described as

$$y[n] = \sum_{k=-n+1}^\infty x[1 - k]$$

I'm not sure how would output for delayed input look like and what would be delayed output here.

Comment: We don't encourage just answering homework problems -- but we give hints.  Try changing the variable in the summation so that you're summing $x[p]$ instead of $x[1 - k]$ (and adjust the limits of summation appropriately).  Take care -- whoever wrote that is playing tricks.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm new to this community so I don't yet understand common practice on this site but nevermind. 
Problem I'm having is in case of shifted output. Am I supposed to "shift limits " of sum and also shift argument of sequence X or I should just change limits of sum

Comment: So this is really a question from (usually) the first couple of chapters of a beginning Calculus text.  You should solve $p = 1 - k$ for $k = -n + 1$ and for $k = \infty$.  Then you should plug those numbers into the limits of the sum.  If you end up with a sum that "runs backwards" (i.e. $\sum_{p = 33}^{-10}$) then just swap the limits (i.e., $\sum_{p = -10}^{33}$).  DSP requires remembering your calculus classes, including the infinite summations and solving difference equations, which always seem to be gone over lightly until they get into the "interesting" stuff.

Comment: Sir, thank you again for answering.
I'm okay with calculus but I would never think of substituting variables like this.
After changing variables I got  I/O equation of accumulator system which is time invariant system.